# Why is part of my bar chart misbehaving?

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I want to plot a histogram-like chart with boxes, in which the bars have different colors.

Here is my data:

```
stage          11402.364    100%    1
App1              78.552    0.69%   2
App2           11323.812    99.30%  2
Read               8.469    0.07%   3
Write             41.285    0.04%   3
Repeat          5748.351    50.41%  3
Count           4933.746    43.27%  3
Count_1         3841.355    33.69%  4
Count_2         1092.391    9.59%   4
```

But I found `lc rgb variable` doesn't work for me. Currently, I am using gnuplot4.2. In 4.2 the third number in using for version 4.2 is boxwidth instead of box color.

But I tried the following method. Since I only need 4 colors, so I try to plot the different color bars manually with the following code:

```
set boxwidth 0.5 relative
set style fill solid 0.5
set xtics rotate
plot 'histogramdata_2.txt' using ($4 == 1 ? $0 : 1/0):2:xtic(1) with boxes lc 1 , \ 
'' using ($4 == 2 ? $0 : 1/0):2:xtic(1) with boxes lc 2 , \
'' using ($4 == 3 ? $0 : 1/0):2:xtic(1) with boxes lc 3 , \
'' using ($4 == 4 ? $0 : 1/0):2:xtic(1) with boxes lc 4
```

This is what I get, which is almost what my want:

[image]

But why the first bar whose 4th column is 1 goes like this? I have tuned for a while, but feel confused. Need some help.

I think it is better to post a new question here, because it is a little different from the original one.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug, which was fixed in 4.6.4 or 4.6.5. I played around a bit with your script and the data set: This bug appears when only a single box is plotted and is not related to the specific `using` filtering. Some other situations:

1. When I remove the "App2" line from the data file, i.e. both for lc 1 and lc 2 there is only one row each, then the first two boxes aren't plotted at all.
2. When I plot only a single box with

   ```
   plot 'histogramdata_2.txt' using 0:2:xtic(1) every ::::0 with boxes
   ```

   I also get this wrong first box
3. Same when filtering externally with `awk`:

   ```
   set boxwidth 0.5 relative
   set style fill solid 0.5
   set xtics rotate
   awk(c, f) = sprintf("awk '{ if ($4 == %d) { print NR, $0 } }' %s", c, f)
   file = 'histogramdata_2.txt'

   set style data boxes
   plot '< '.awk(1, file) using 1:3:xtic(2), \
        '< '.awk(2, file) using 1:3:xtic(2), \
        '< '.awk(3, file) using 1:3:xtic(2), \
        '< '.awk(4, file) using 1:3:xtic(2)
   ```

No, I found no workaround for this (I also tried including some dummy values and skipping them with appropriate `set xrange`, but that didn't work).

Comment: So from which version, the `lc rgb variable` is supported? Currently, I am using 4.2. I am planning to update the tool...

Comment: I don't know, but if you're upgrading anyway you should go to the newest version, i.e. 5.0